# Stripe.js requires 'allow-same-origin' if sandboxed

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open the payment gateway (checkout page) of stripe js. I did this:

```
 async function LoadPaymentController(){
      var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51JBxkrB1SsiUQAfnzEWMqNgSCr9yV7tvULhePuQxwP3iCVr1kkNZskUA51TOtE5gw7f1X1ZSw41FKbHoIAHDolgI00DStmrT1m');
    // Call your backend to create the Checkout Session
    fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
      method: 'POST',
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(session) {
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
      // error, you should display the localized error message to your
      // customer using `error.message`.
      if (result.error) {
        alert(result.error.message);
      }
    });
    }
```

This function is called when a button is clicked in my page. But it returns the error

```
Stripe.js requires 'allow-same-origin' if sandboxed
```

When I google that, I only find examples of this being used inside an iframe, which I am not doing.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You try to open the link in your own page, it has to go directly to stripe. No iframe or in your own page is allowed if i understood it wel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) (CSP) related.

There have been some changes/additions to CSP that major browsers have recently implemented:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox
- https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_iframe_sandbox-allow-same-origin

From your server, I'd try adding the following CSP directive/header to your document (ie. your main HTML document for the page or client bundle entry point)

```
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox allow-same-origin;
```

If you don't already have a mechanism for doing this with your chosen framework, you might consider something like this NPM package for React: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csp

You could also try an extension like this (for Chrome) to disable CSP on the page while you're developing, to confirm CSP is the issue:

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-disable-content-se/ffelghdomoehpceihalcnbmnodohkibj?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem that you have, exactly the same error, I tried to install the extensions provided there but nothing seems to be helpful, after investigation, I found that my client wasn't hosted, and stripe take CORS seriously, even in testing, so to test and run your application you should use this command to start a local server:

```bash
npx serve -p 3000
```

This commend should be run inside the folder that holds `index.html`.