# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' using Stripe on rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe payment in my rails 7 app and the stripe form does not show.
when i check inspect element in browser, this error shows:

```
    Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://js.stripe.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3000').
```

**purchases/show.html.erb**

```rb
<h1>Purchase <%= @product.name %></h1>

<%= form_with url: product_purchase_path(@product), local: true, id: "payment-form", data: { payment_intent_id: @payment_intent.client_secret} do |form| %>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
    </div>

    <div id="card-element" class: "form-control">
    </div>

    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name on Card</label>
    <%= form.text_field :name_on_card, placeholder: "Full Name", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.hidden_field :payment_intent_id, value: @payment_intent.id %>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit Payment</button>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Application.js**

```js
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
  const public_key = document.querySelector("meta[name= 'stripe-key']").getAttribute("content")
  const stripe = Stripe(public_key)

  const elements = stripe.elements()
  const card = elements.create('card')
  card.amount('#card-element')

  card.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors')
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = ''
    }
  })
})
```

This there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because Stripe only allows `https` connections for security reasons. To resolve this issue you either serve your app over `https` or you can use a Tool such as `ngrok`

1. Download and install ngrok from the official website (https://ngrok.com/)
2. Start your rails app `rails serve`
3. Start ngrok by running the following command in a seperate window

   ```
   ngrok http 3000
   ```
4. This will start a secure public url (e.g. https://your-unique-subdomain.ngrok.io ) that you can use to access your local development environment. Use this URL in your Stripe form and try accessing the page again.

Comment: now forwarding through ngrok but i am still getting the same error: `(index):1 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://js.stripe.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://f1c4-102-176-65-53.eu.ngrok.io'). `

Comment: Maybe look into this...?! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70154598/stripe-js-requires-allow-same-origin-if-sandboxed
Are you using react or any frontend framework? Or just "vanilla" javascript

Comment: i am not using any frontend framework. my payment button submits and stripe logs getts 200 and payment processes but the element form do not show. i am updating this post with the view and javascript. please look it up for me